# Is there any chance for icon change(from local path img) in angular ng2-fan-menu

Tags: angular, sass

I'm setting up ng2 fan menu, and want to support change of icons, where do I changes in .ts or css.

I have tried change of `background-image : url("assets/images/logo1.png");` but its not changed, its taking default option icon name i.e. `'icon': {'name': 'fas fa-headphones'}`

```
`public wings = [
  {
      'title': 'option1',
      'color': '#D6D4D4',
      'icon': {'name': 'fas fa-headphones'}
  }, {
      'title': 'B',
      'color': '#D6D4D4',
      'icon': {'name': 'fas fa-desktop'}
  }, {
      'title': 'C',
      'color': '#D6D4D4',
      'icon': {'name': 'fas fa-mobile'}
  }, {
      'title': 'D',
      'color': '#D6D4D4',
      'icon': {'name': 'fas fa-stroopwafel'}
  }, {
    'title': 'E',
    'color': '#D6D4D4',
    'icon': {'name': 'fas fa-laptop'}
}, {
    'title': 'F',
    'color': '#D6D4D4',
    'icon': {'name': 'fa fa-laptop'}
}
];`
```

I have expected change of icon with my local assets/images/logo1.png..etc images.

**Solution**
`

```
<i class="{{wing.icon.name}}"
       #wingIconElm
       *ngIf="menuConfig.showIcons || menuConfig.onlyIcons"
       [ngStyle]="{
            'color': wing.icon.color || menuConfig.wingFontColor,
            'font-size': iconSize + 'px',
            'width': iconSize + 'px',
            'height': iconSize + 'px'
       }"></i>
```

`Replaced with`

```
<img src="{{wing.icon.name}}" class="{{wing.icon.name}}"
       #wingIconElm
       *ngIf="menuConfig.showIcons || menuConfig.onlyIcons"
       [ngStyle]="{
            'color': wing.icon.color || menuConfig.wingFontColor,
            'font-size': iconSize + 'px',
            'width': iconSize + 'px',
            'height': iconSize + 'px'
       }">
```

`

Comment: What you tried to do that?

Comment: i need to update the local icon instead of font awsome [fas fa-mobile]..

Comment: i need to update the local icon instead of font awsome [fas fa-mobile]..

Comment: Please create an example or include your code.

Comment: `<code><app-menu-container class="menu-container-btn" [options]="options"  (click)="settingsOption()"              
                  [gutter]="gutter"                   
                  [startAngles]="startAngles"                 
                  [wings]="wings">M</app-menu-container><code>

Comment: public options = { "radius": "45", "onlyIcons": true, "offset": "5",  "buttonWidth": "25",    "wingIconSize": "13",    "angle": "60",    "buttonCrossImgSize": "5%",    "buttonBackgroundColor": "#D6D4D4",    "buttonFontColor": "#36615c"};